# JSON array values, appending to URL and refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to do a form of URL cycling but instead of given URLS, I want to append values from a JSON object to the url and cycle those.

I have the main idea working but it's not quite right. Right now the link to the page in question carries a value for 'display' so an example would be

```
showdisplay.php?display=3
```

This runs a query to get all page info for any pages assigned to display 3, and this works.

What I want, once that query returns my result which is then JSON encoded, is to loop throught the JSON object, append the `pageID` of the first element in the URL, and after the `duration` of the element (in seconds) refresh the page and do the same thing again. Continue looping this and going back to the first element at the end of the object.

SO given this JSON object:

```
[{"pageID":"104",
    "display_id":"3",
    "duration":"56",
    "page_id":"104",
},
{"pageID":"116",
    "display_id":"3",
    "duration":"54",
    "page_id":"116",
}]
```

Here's what I expect when clicking the link ```Link to Page:

1. On immediate pageload, the URL would be `showdisplay.php?display=3&pageID=104`
2. After 56 seconds ('duration' in JSON), refresh page and set URL to `showdisplay.php?display=3&pageID=116`
3. After 54 seconds, refresh again back to pageID 104

Basically, when following that link, the url should never just say `showdisplay.php?display=3` but should always have a pageID assinged to it from the JSON

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let obj = <?php echo $showDisplays; ?>;

let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
params.set("pageID", obj[0].pageID);
params.set("display", obj[0].display_id);
let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = nextURL;
}, obj.duration * 1000);

obj.forEach(function(o){console.log(o)})
</script>
```

I've been stuck on this for days and have no idea what I'm doing wrong or how to loop this properly. I feel like it shouldn't be too dificult but I'm not a JS coder by nature and I'm totally stuck. Can anyone help me rectify this and loop properly?

Comment: I deleted that and cleaned it up a bit with a different json here

Comment: @Andreas this is more clear for what I expect